# What is thie cube around my meshes

Tags: mesh

I have a model edited with blender. I selected all my meshes and made CTRL-A to reset scale and location. Since then, 8 of my meshes have some akward kind ob cube around them. What is it and how can I hide these cubes? I must have done a bad manipulation here but I don't know when and how I made it. Google is not helping me there neither.

[image]

Comment: Looks like texture space visualization. Head over to the properties panel -> Object tab -> Display -> turn off *Texture space*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jerryno said as comment, it is a texture space visualization. that can be hiden in object tag -> Display